# C language strlen function with new line character in the string

Tags: c, string, newline, strlen

Generally strlen() function in C language returns unsigned int but if the string has new line character then what will be the output ?
For example :
What will be the output of strlen("stack\n") in C language ?

Comment: regarding: *strlen() function in C language returns unsigned int*  No, what it returns is `size_t` which is another name for `unsigned long int`

Comment: @user3629249 `size_t` might be `unsigned long`, `unsigned` or some other _unsigned_ type with a range of at least [0--65535].

Comment: How is the presence of a `\n` related to the return type of `strlen`? Seems completely unrelated.

Comment: It is unrelated.  man strlen or straight Google gives the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen("stack\n")` --> 6.  Nothing special about `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

> "*What will be the output of `strlen("stack\n")`?*"

`6`. The newline character such as any character except `'\0'` (NUL) is counted as any  character else.

> "*Generally `strlen()` function in C language returns `unsigned int`.*"

That is not correct. `strlen()` returns a `size_t` value which is quite a distinct type from `unsigned int`, although in most implementations `size_t` can be an alias for `unsigned int`. But to keep the difference is important.

---

Note: If the string is stored in an `char` array instead (it is not a string literal and with that immutable) and you want to remove the newline, you can use `strcspn()`:

```
char a[7] = "stack\n";        // 7 elements, not 6. Required to store terminating NUL.

printf("%zu\n", strlen(a));   // This will print 6.

a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = 0;      // Replace newline with NUL.

printf("%zu", strlen(a));     // This will print 5.
```